# Prometheus blackbox_exporter didn't skip SSL checking

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I've enabled the insecure_skip_verify parameter in config, but blackbox_exporter still failed in SSL checking.

```
modules:
  http_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 5s
    http:
      valid_http_versions: ["HTTP/1.1", "HTTP/2.0"]
      method: GET
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
      ip_protocol_fallback: false
      no_follow_redirects: false
      fail_if_ssl: false
      fail_if_not_ssl: false
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true

root@monitor-1:~# curl "http://localhost:9115/probe?target=https://www.263.com&module=http_2xx&debug=true"
Logs for the probe:
ts=2021-01-19T13:26:02.336532681Z caller=main.go:304 module=http_2xx target=https://www.263.com level=info msg="Beginning probe" probe=http timeout_seconds=119.5
ts=2021-01-19T13:26:02.33679155Z caller=http.go:342 module=http_2xx target=https://www.263.com level=info msg="Resolving target address" ip_protocol=ip6
ts=2021-01-19T13:26:02.341423219Z caller=http.go:342 module=http_2xx target=https://www.263.com level=info msg="Resolved target address" ip=211.150.65.26
ts=2021-01-19T13:26:02.341519047Z caller=client.go:252 module=http_2xx target=https://www.263.com level=info msg="Making HTTP request" url=https://211.150.65.26 host=www.263.com
ts=2021-01-19T13:26:02.354176072Z caller=main.go:119 module=http_2xx target=https://www.263.com level=error msg="Error for HTTP request" err="Get \"https://211.150.65.26\": x509: certificate is valid for *.263.net, 263.net, not www.263.com"
ts=2021-01-19T13:26:02.354254679Z caller=main.go:119 module=http_2xx target=https://www.263.com level=info msg="Response timings for roundtrip" roundtrip=0 start=2021-01-19T13:26:02.34163085Z dnsDone=2021-01-19T13:26:02.34163085Z connectDone=2021-01-19T13:26:02.345415737Z gotConn=0001-01-01T00:00:00Z responseStart=0001-01-01T00:00:00Z end=0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
ts=2021-01-19T13:26:02.354307734Z caller=main.go:304 module=http_2xx target=https://www.263.com level=error msg="Probe failed" duration_seconds=0.017698452
```

Comment: Thans for your question (as it showed me the correct YAML format), I tested it and it works but it returns a 404 status code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the HTTPS with HTTP in the target:

```
curl "http://localhost:9115/probe?target=http://www.263.com&module=http_2xx&debug=true"
```

Comment: I wanted to check if the https service is alive.

Comment: So, you need to set "fail_if_not_ssl: true", but I think you can't connect through HTTPS with a wrong certificate, can you?

Comment: insecure_skip_verify: true

Should this skip the certificate cheching?

Comment: I found the root cause, the config of blackbox didn't take into effect for unknown reason. I will change it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case changes in blackbox config didn't take effect, try to restart the blackbox exporter service